# Would Arduino be the most viable language to support the construction of a human-like robot?

Tags: arduino, robotics

If you wanted to build a human-like robot, what language would be most suitable?

Arduino?

Or would you need to write mostly low-level microcontroller-level code at the 1s and 0s level?

Comment: Arduino isn't a language, it's a prototyping platform that uses Atmel AVR microcontrollers. With some additional information, this might be a good question to ask on [Electronics Engineering StackExchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: its perfectly language, http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/HomePage

Answer (score 3):

There's probably a few people typing the same response as I type...

The term Arduino can be a bit confusing for beginners. There is the Arduino microcontroller, which stores the executable code and contains inputs and outputs, and the Arduino IDE, which compiles code and uploads it to the Arduino microcontroller. As mentioned in [How is programming an Arduino different than standard C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931572/how-is-programming-an-arduino-different-than-standard-c/5931887#5931887), the programming language used to program the Arduino microcontroller is C or C++.

If a human-like robot is defined as a basic robot with two legs that move in a predefined routine, an Arduino should suffice.

To get started building a robot using an Arduino, [Beginning Arduino](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430232404) and [Arduino Robotics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430231831) are two recent books that have been getting good reviews. I recommend starting with one of these books. If you have questions specific to microcontrollers or electronics, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ would be a good resource.